# Philadelphia SUG: Hedgehog Demo Night: Feydra & TDS

Tags: discussion, status-completed, community-event

- Local Date/Time: Wed, March 15, 2017 @ 6:00pm
- UTC Date/Time: Wed, March 15, 2017 @ 11:00pm
- Location: CityCoHo, 2401 Walnut Street, Suite 102, Philadelphia, PA
- Link: https://www.meetup.com/Sitecore-User-Group-Philadelphia/events/238224513/
- Who to Contact: zkniebel@delphicdigital.com
- Description: (below)

**An Overview of Hedgehog's Tools and Modules**

On this exciting demo night, Hedgehog Solutions Architect and Sitecore MVP, Sean Holmesby, will speak about some of the different tools and modules that Hedgehog have created to improve the Sitecore development experience. He will be talking about both Hedgehog's enterprise tools and open source modules they've created. In particular he will be demoing:

- Feydra, Hedgehog's latest tool for front end developers
- TDS and the new features in the upcoming release, version 5.6

While also discussing

- Razl and some of the lesser known features for comparison and migration
- The Sitecore Package Deployer module
- The Field Fallback module
- The Scheduled Publishing module
- The Placeholder Fallback module
- Helix FxCop Rules
- ...and more....

Pizza and beer will be provided.

Comment: Community Bulletin promotion began yesterday. Well it would have, if I managed to create the event sooner ;-)

Comment: Hahaha awesome! Thanks, man!